# Send magic packet when local IP is accessed

Tags: macos, networking, wake-on-lan, tomato, magic-packet

I have a Mac Mini with WOL enabled that's running a few media servers on different ports (8080 and 8082). In dd-wrt, by default, if the Mini was asleep, then attempting to access its static ip on one of those ports (any port, if I remember correctly) would cause it to wake up and resume the servers. In Tomato USB, this is not the case. The best I can do (after adding a firewall script that keeps the mac+ip on the ARP table indefinitely) is wake it up from the Tools/WOL menu.

Is there some sort of script I can run that can repeat Tomato's WOL function whenever a device in the LAN attempts to send a packet specifically to it? Using broadcast IPs or a WOL app or anything else that would require more than simply attempting to access one of the servers on it is not a solution in this case.